# Validate whether multiple fields are unique simultaneously in laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

This my request class rules.

```
return [
        'title' => 'required|unique:event_cals,title',
        'eventDate' => 'required|date|after:yesterday',
        'venue' => 'required',
        'time' => 'required',
        'type' => 'required',
        'unique:event_cals,eventDate,NULL,id,venue,$request->venue,time,$request->time'
    ];
```

I want to validate a rule like below.

```
        'eventDate' && 'venue' && 'time' => 'unique'
```

There I need to check if there any row without same eventDate, venue and time altogether. Anyone knows how to declare such a rule?

This is the snapshot of db table.
[image]

Comment: try custom validation https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#custom-validation-rules

Comment: Can you help me with a sample code please?

Comment: You can not use variables between single quotes using php. You also probably should make sure that input and db matches exactly. You also did not specify the column being validated

Comment: Please can you come up with the code for that line. Input fields and db column names are similar here

Comment: @ A. Wen did you manage to get this to work as I am trying to do the same thing but struggling? Thanks

Comment: Check my answer here [How to create custom validation rule for multiple uniqueness in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42115930/laravel-form-validation-unique-using-2-fields#answer-49367371)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the possible solution:

```
<?php

return [
    'title'      => 'required|unique:event_cals,title',
    'eventDate'  => 'required|date|after:yesterday',
    'venue'      => 'required',
    'time'       => 'required',
    'type'       => 'required',
    'event_date' => "unique:event_cals,event_date,NULL,id,venue,{$request->venue},time,{$request->time}",
];
```

I again want to highlight that; if you want that validator to work, you should make sure that the event_date and time should be correctly formatted.

An example unique check with additional wheres from our running project's update requests:

```
/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    $id = $this->route('money');

    return $rules = [
        'name'       => "required|string|min:3|max:255|unique:moneys,name,{$id},id,deleted_at,NULL,access,public",
    ];
}
```

Comment: 'event_date' => 'unique:event_cals,event_date,NULL,id,venue,{$request->venue},time,{$request->time}'   This also not validated know. That means I can add a row which has eventDate,venue and time  values similar to already added rows.

Comment: Can you check db logs and share or debug pls. I can't know what's going on there

Comment: I updated the answer with db picture. There both two rows eventDate,time,venue are equal. I want to validate to avoid that. Simply, there can't be two events which are happening on same eventDate,time and venue.