# Laravel custom validation with many parameters

Tags: php, laravel

I have to following customized validation

```
Validator::extend('uniqueFirstAndLastName', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
        $count = DB::table('people')->where('firstName', $value)
            ->where('lastName', $parameters[0])
            ->where('id', '<>', $parameters[1])
            ->count();

        return $count === 0;
    });
```

How do I call this rule with the 2nd parameter since $parameters expects an array?

This does not work:

```
return Validator::make($data, [
            'firstName' => "uniqueFirstAndLastName:{$data['lastName]},{$data['id']}"
]
```

Comment: Your validation, even if it would work, will produce false positives. Why? Because you're delegating uniqueness check to PHP and PHP (or any other language) **cannot guarantee uniqueness**. Only the underlying database can. That means - you need to place **unique** constraints on desired column(s) and perform an insert. If you get exception with code `23000` then the record exists and you notify the user that those credentials have been taken. Create a `binary` column that contains a hash of first and last name, make it unique, simply insert and catch the exception. Everything else will fail.

Comment: I'm using laravel validation and I prefer to make the checking on the php side rather with an index on these 2 fields.

This validation rule works great. the only missing part is that it needs to exclude the current record being checked with the rest of the table.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42115930/laravel-form-validation-unique-using-2-fields/42116158#42116158

Comment: Your preference doesn't make something what you need it to be. You'll end up with duplicated names in the end, even on a low-traffic website - I've seen it happen so many times and the solution is always to constrain the records on database side. If you don't want to do it, that's another pair of sleeves. I wrote the comment to warn you, but since you  think it's wise to proceed - let's wait for some nice soul to give you a gun to shoot your foot :) good luck with this!

Comment: Looks like you are trying to make a bicycle out of a car  It should be mentioned as well that there is no need to pass `$data` params into validator rule directly - they are already there in `$validator->getData()`

Comment: I don't want tu be rude, but if someone shows a direction where to go, you would look at his finger.
My question isn't about unique, which you've been focusing since the beginning. 
My question is about : how to call a custom validation function with an array for the argument 'parameters'.

Comment: If I see you in the street and ask you to show me the closest bakery, you will show me a butcher and argue that bread will kill me and meat is better for my health?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a var_dump inside the custome validator function, I was able to see the content of its parameters.

The answer to this question is simply separating values by comma like so:

```
return Validator::make($data, [
            'firstName' => "uniqueFirstAndLastName:{$data['lastName]},{$data['id']}"
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

As Mjh said, it's always a got practice to add a constrain on the database.

however, you might try this approach,

```
Validator::make($data, [
    'lastName' => [
        'required',
        "unique:people,lastName,{$ignoredUserId},firstName,{$data['lastName']}'"
    ],
]);
```

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-unique

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but after trying your code, it shows the following error:

ErrorException in ValidatesAttributes.php line 721:
Undefined offset: 1

And as other people, my question isn't about unique rule, please read again the original question.